# Building a function that divides dataframe into groups

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am intrested in creating a function that does the folloing:

1. accepts 2 parameters: a DataFrame and an integer.
2. adds a column to the DF called "group"
3. giving each row an integer based on his integer location. the number of groups should be as the number of integer given to the function.
4. if the number of rows is not dividable by the integer given, the remaning rows should be **splitted as evenly as possible between the groups**. this is the part im having problems with.

Here is a menual exemple i made to clarify my intentions:

I would to get from this DF:

```
d = {'value': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13],}
df_init = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

By this function:

```
wanted function(df_init,5)
```

To this finel DF:

```
s = {'value': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13],'group':[1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,5,5]}
df_finel = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

If I can make the question any clearer, please tell me how and ill fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Use `np.array_split`

```
In [5481]: [i for i, x in enumerate(np.array_split(np.arange(len(df)), 5), 1) for _ in x]
Out[5481]: [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5]
```

Assign it

```
In [5487]: df['group'] = [i for i, x in 
                          enumerate(np.array_split(np.arange(len(df)), 5), 1) for _ in x]

In [5488]: df
Out[5488]:
    value  group
0       1      1
1       2      1
2       3      1
3       4      2
4       5      2
5       6      2
6       7      3
7       8      3
8       9      3
9      10      4
10     11      4
11     12      5
12     13      5
```

---

Details

<sub>Original df</sub>

```
In [5491]: df
Out[5491]:
    value
0       1
1       2
2       3
3       4
4       5
5       6
6       7
7       8
8       9
9      10
10     11
11     12
12     13
```

The act

```
In [5492]: np.array_split(np.arange(len(df)), 5)
Out[5492]:
[array([0, 1, 2]),
 array([3, 4, 5]),
 array([6, 7, 8]),
 array([ 9, 10]),
 array([11, 12])]
```

Comment: great solution would be nice if you write the same in a function.